# How to add twitter timeline in community page

Tags: community, community-builder, twitter

I am working with `Lightning Community builder` and i need to add the `Twitter TimeLine` in the page, i already have the `custom component` for the `twitter timeline`, but i don't know how to configure it, so when it's published it appears in the `community page` with the tweets, and i want also to know what value i put in the `Twitter handle` input.

here's an image of the  lightning community builder page

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the component from ?

Comment: i was assigned to work in a project, and when they gave me access i found it there, i suppose it's from appexchane, i am not sure

Comment: This is awesome. Is there any way this can be shared? We're looking for something like this for our community, but unable to find such a thing on the AppExchange.

Comment: This is not a component from the appexchange, it's a custom component thats was implemented. I cannot share it here, if you want give your email and i send it to you